# Error:Minifying the variant used for tests is not supported when using Jack

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am getting this error in Android studio when i enable jackOptions in build.gradle

> Error:Minifying the variant used for tests is not supported when using
>   Jack

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`jackOptions` is not required longer. Java 8 is supported on `Android Studio 3.0`

> Jack is no longer supported, and you should first [disable Jack](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html#disable_jack) to use
>   the improved Java 8 support built into the default toolchain.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support.html)

Answer (score 3):

The Jack toolchain is deprecated. Use the new gradle plugin, and you'll also get rid of this error. Follow [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html) to migrate your app.

Comment: bro i already updated `Gradle version to 3.3 & Android Plugin Version to 2.3.3` according to [doc](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/java8-support.html) i removed jackOptions block but it gives another error - `Error:Jack is required to support java 8 language features. Either enable Jack or remove sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8`